# Help with a Refactoring: Introduce Parameter Object?

Tags: java, refactoring, parameter-object

I have some code which is the same except that a certain sequence of assignments happen in slightly different orders.

It is easy to factor this out into a method parameter of type `int[]`, which denotes the order.

However, I find it isn't the clearest.

Another option was to factor them out into a object of type `AssignmentOrders`.  I can also do validation on the values in the object constructor that I wasn't able to do with the array.  This would be the "Introduce Parameter Objects" refactoring from the book, *Refactoring*.

I am wondering if this particular refactoring is overkill and I should just stick with the `int[]`?

CODE:

Three Samples of the Originals:

```
private static PersonDetails parseLine(String line, String deliminator, int[] orderOfSections) 
            throws Exception {
        String[] sections = line.split(deliminator);

        String value1 = sections[0].trim();
        String value2 = sections[1].trim();
        String value3 = sections[4].trim();
        String value4 = sections[2].trim();
        String value5 = sections[3].trim();

        //........
    }

private static PersonDetails parseLine(String line, String deliminator) 
            throws Exception {
        String[] sections = line.split(deliminator);

        String value1 = sections[1].trim();
        String value2 = sections[0].trim();
        String value3 = sections[2].trim();
        String value4 = sections[3].trim();
        String value5 = sections[4].trim();

        //........
    }

private static PersonDetails parseLine(String line, String deliminator, int[] orderOfSections)


        throws Exception {
        String[] sections = line.split(deliminator);

        String value1 = sections[0].trim();
        String value2 = sections[1].trim();
        String value3 = sections[2].trim();
        String value4 = sections[4].trim();
        String value5 = sections[5].trim();

        //........
    }
```

How I've refactored the above 3 into this:

```
private static PersonDetails parseLine(String line, String deliminator, int[] orderOfSections) 
            throws Exception {
        String[] sections = line.split(deliminator);

        String value1 = sections[orderOfSections[0]].trim();
        String value2 = sections[orderOfSections[1]].trim();
        String value3 = sections[orderOfSections[2]].trim();
        String value4 = sections[orderOfSections[3]].trim();
        String value5 = sections[orderOfSections[4]].trim();

        //........
    }
```

How I could theoretically refactor it into a parameter object:

```
private static PersonDetails parseLine(String line, String deliminator, OrderOfSections order) 
        throws Exception {
        String[] sections = line.split(deliminator);

        String value1 = sections[order.getValue1Idx].trim();
        String value2 = sections[order.getValue2Idx].trim();
        String value3 = sections[order.getValue3Idx].trim();
        String value4 = sections[order.getValue4Idx].trim();
        String value5 = sections[order.getValue5Idx].trim();

        //........
    }
```

What I was thinking of doing was creating a specific class instead of using `int[]`... But wondered if that would be overkill.

The benefits are that it would be more readable.  Instead of `orderOfSections[0]`, it might be `orderOfSections.value1SectionIdx`...  I could also put some validation code into the class.

I believe this is what Martin Fowler calls Introducing a Parameter Object.

EDIT:

Another option would be to use a Dictionary.  Lighter-weight than a new class, but more descriptive...  Then I could use something like `orderOfSections["value1"]`

Comment: You need to post the code you want to refactor otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Ok okok ok ok  I"m working on it already!

Comment: You'd be better off trying at http://refactormycode.com/.

Comment: I've read the question, and I still don't understand what you want to do or why. Sorry.

Comment: Doesn't really look like C# to me. Java perhaps?

Comment: yeah Java, I didn't put the C# tag, someone else must have!

Comment: a very important detail missing is what is the source of the ordering supplies in the int array.  Are these orders hardcoded somewhere, are they specific in some kind of configuration, are they user generated in some other way?

Comment: I guess this idea was crazy.  Hehe.

Comment: Not necessarily crazy, just a different kind of change.

Comment: What I see is a reasonable refactoring - interface details apart.  I wonder though if the problem isn't upstream from this code, in whatever methods load the data into the sections in the 'wrong order'?

Comment: I am tempted to submit this sample to thedailywtf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of passing in a `Class` or array that simply indicates the ordering of the items in the raw `String` and how they should be assigned, I would delegate the parsing of the input `line` to this `Class`.  It would be much more readable to do the following:

```
private static PersonDetails parseLine(String line, String deliminator, 
                         SectionsReader reader) throws Exception 
{
    reader.setLine(line);
    String value1 = reader.getValue1();
    String value2 = reader.getValue2();
    String value3 = reader.getValue3();
    String value4 = reader.getValue4();
    String value5 = reader.getValue5();

    //........
}
```

In the end, this would not be overkill, and you will thank yourself in 3 months' time when you go back to this code and find it more intelligible.

Comment: ooooh, very nice, thank you.  See I knew this code could be refactored for better readability and thus better maintainability.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the simplest and most readable way is to pass a map instead of an int array.

And depending on what your fields for PersonDetails look like, you could even use reflection and assign the values in a loop.

Comment: For my purposes I think this suits me best.